# Would freezing a whole pineapple change it visually?

Tags: fruit

If I freeze a whole pineapple with skin and stalk left attached, is the color likely to be affected?
The fruit will be used for a fruit tray display only, so taste is not a concern.

Thanks!

Comment: How long do you need to store them?

Comment: As soon as it is in the Refrigerator it will be OK but after you take it out of it then it will get in touch with outer atmosphere and it will start getting warm. So by then may be shape might change. And it depends on that as well that for how much time you need it on display.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are displaying the whole pineapple, then you don't need to freeze it. Pineapples will maintain their appearance for quite a long time which is why they were able to be shipped around the world during the age of sail.

To help it keep a bit longer, each day stand the pineapple up on end and drizzle water into the leaf crown. This is how this plant gets most of it water and nutrients and it will help keep the fruit hydrated for a little longer than ordinary.